# Implement GAM in T-SQL

Tags: r, mgcv

I use R to build all my models but leverage T-SQL to score all datasets since the datasets I score are typically 20+ million observations. I am trying to figure out how to take the GAM Object from the `mgcv` package and code it in T-SQL much the same way I do logistic and linear regression models. The things I believe I would need to know for a give gam Object are what type of smoothing was used for each predictor, what are the knots for each spline, etc. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very pertinent question, clearly formulated. Shows on on top when googling `gam.predict sql`.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a method for extracting models from GAMs that could be easily transferred to SQL. These models have local assessment of curvature that might be difficult to extract. They can be a separate model at each point. I would wonder if you could use the predict.gam facilities in that package to record matrices from a multi-dimensional grid, and then do spline interpolation.

I have used the rms/Hmisc package facilities for extraction of a function from 'cph' and 'lrm' models. The 'rms' facilities (the `Function` function in particular) can extract from models that are as complex as two-way, crossed spline terms constructed using the `%ia%` operation. I have had some difficulty (in estimation) with rcs-terms that exceed 3 degrees of freedom and sometimes need to restrict the location of the knots in some instances to maintain numerical stability.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information. You are always very helpful.